# How does the Haskell `do` notation know which value to take when it isn't defined by a return?

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, do-notation

I have this monadic object.

```hs
data Parser a = Parser (String -> Maybe (a, String))

instance Functor Parser where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
  fmap f (Parser pa) =  Parser $ \input -> case pa input of
                                             Nothing -> Nothing
                                             Just (a, rest) -> Just (f a, rest)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Parser where
  --return :: a -> Parser a
  return a =  Parser $ \input -> Just (a, input)

  --(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
  (Parser pa) >>= f  = Parser $ \input -> case pa input of
                                            Nothing -> Nothing
                                            Just (a,rest) -> parse (f a) rest
```

And I have this definition of an `item` which I am told "reads in a character" but I don't really see any reading going on.

```hs
item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \ input -> case input of ""    -> Nothing
                                         (h:t) -> Just (h, t)
```

But ok, fine, maybe I should just relax about how literal to take the word "read" and jibe with it.  Moving on, I have

```hs
failParse :: Parser a
failParse = Parser $ \ input -> Nothing

sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do c <- item
           if p c
           then return c
           else failParse
```

And this is where I get pretty confused.  What is getting stored in the variable `c`?  Since `item` is a `Parser` with parameter `Char`, my first guess is that `c` is storing such an object.  But after a second of thought I know that's not now the `do` notation works, you don't get the monad, you get the contents of the monad.  Great, but then that tells me `c` is then the function

```hs
\ input -> case input of ""    -> Nothing
                         (h:t) -> Just (h, t)
```

But clearly that's wrong since the next line of the definition of `sat` treats `c` like a character.  Not only is that not what I expect, but it's about three levels of structure down from what I expected!  It's not the function, it's not the `Maybe` object, and it's not the tuple, but it's the left coordinate of the `Just` tuple buried inside the function!  How is that little character working all that way outside?  What is instructing the `<-` to extract this part of the monad?

Comment: do notation just be syntax sugar, de-sugar your case is: item >>= (\c->if p c then return c else failParse). see: [link] (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comment mentioned, `<-` just be [do notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) syntax sugar and equivalent to:

```
item >>= (\c->if p c 
              then return c 
              else failParse)
```

Okay, let see what is `c`? consider the definition of `(>>=)`

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
```

or more readable way:

```
Parser a >>= (a -> Parser b)
```

And Now, matches it with above expression `item >>= (\c->if p c then return c else failParse)` give:

```
Parer a = item
```

and

```
(a->Parser b) = (\c->if p c then return c else failParse)
```

and `item` has type:

```
item :: Parser Char
```

so, we can now replace `a` in `(>>=)` by Char, gives

```
Parser Char >>= (Char -> Parser b)
```

and now `\c->if p c then return c else failParse` also have type: `(Char -> Parser b)`

and so `c` is a Char, and the whole expression can be extended to:

```
sat p =
item >>= (\c->...) = 
Parser pa >= (\c->...) = Parser $ \input -> case pa input of
                                            Nothing -> Nothing
                                            Just (a,rest) -> parse (f a) rest
                         where f c =  if p c
                                      then return c
                                      else failParse
                               pa input = case input of ""   -> Nothing
                                                       (h:t) -> Just (h, t)
```

Comment: @WillNess maybe you are right, the parameter c in (\c->...) finally replace by the output of function inside item (i.e. pa in Parser pa). but if pa return Nothing, (\c->...) will not be applied, so semantically, we can't say c == Nothing, as c never be replaced by Nothing.  So, I am not assign any meaning to (<-), since the actual meaning must refers to definition of (>>=). But for accuracy, I shall delete the term 'extract nothing' from my answer

Comment: Yes, so <- eventually replaced by >>=, the expression below <- become a function on the right-hand side of >>=, and c on the left of <- become the parameter of the function. and so, what <- do?

Comment: "extracts" a value.

Comment: Okay, fine. but I still prefer to translate <- to >>= and see  how >>= defined on specific instance. It is accuracy and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR:* In general, by Monad laws,

```hs
do { item }
```

is the same as

```hs
do { c <- item
   ; return c
   }
```

so it *is* defined by a `return`, in a sense. Details follow.

---

It does take one character out from the input string which is being *"read"*, so in this sense it *"reads"* that character:

```hs
item :: Parser                                   Char
item = Parser $ \ input ->          -- input :: [Char]   
             case input of { ""    -> Nothing
                           ; (h:t) -> Just (h, t)  -- (h:t) :: [Char]
                           }             -- h :: Char    t  :: [Char]
```

and I bet there's a definition

```hs
parse (Parser pa) input = pa input
```

defined there somewhere; so

```hs
parse item input = case input of { ""    -> Nothing 
                                 ; (h:t) -> Just (h, t) }
```

Next, what does `(>>=)` mean? It means that

```hs
parse (Parser pa >>= f) input = case (parse (Parser pa) input) of
                     Nothing             -> Nothing
                     Just (a, leftovers) -> parse (f a) leftovers
```

i.e.

```hs
parse (item      >>= f) input
      = case (parse  item  input) of
                     Nothing             -> Nothing
                     Just (a, leftovers) -> parse (f a) leftovers
      = case (case input of { "" -> Nothing 
                            ; (h:t) -> Just (h, t) 
                            }) of
                     Nothing             -> Nothing
                     Just (a, leftovers) -> parse (f a) leftovers
      = case input of 
           ""    ->                         Nothing 
           (h:t) -> case Just (h, t) of {
                         Just (a, leftovers) -> parse (f a) leftovers }
      = case input of 
           ""    -> Nothing 
           (h:t) -> parse (f h) t
```

Now,

```hs
-- sat p: a "satisfies `p`" parser 
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do { c <- item           -- sat p :: Parser Char
           ; if p c              -- item  :: Parser Char,  c :: Char
                then return c    -- return c  :: Parser Char
                else failParse   -- failParse :: Parser Char
           }
      = item >>= (\ c ->
                    if p c then return c else failParse)
```

(by unraveling the `do` syntax), and so

```hs
parse (sat p) input 
 = parse (item >>= (\ c ->
                    if p c then return c else failParse)) input
   -- parse (item >>= f) input
   --  = case input of { "" -> Nothing ; (h:t) -> parse (f h) t }
 = case input of 
       ""    -> Nothing 
       (h:t) -> parse ((\ c -> if p c then (return c)
                                       else failParse) h) t
 = case input of 
       ""    -> Nothing 
       (c:t) -> parse (if p c then (return c) 
                               else failParse) t
 = case input of 
       ""    -> Nothing 
       (c:t) -> if p c then parse (return c) t
                               else parse failParse t
 = case input of 
       ""    -> Nothing 
       (c:t) -> if p c then Just (c, t)
                               else Nothing
```

Now the meaning of `sat p` should be clear: for `c` produced by `item` (which is the first character in the input, if input is non-empty), if `p c` holds, `c` is accepted and the parse succeeds, otherwise the parse fails:

```hs
sat p = for c from item:                 -- do { c <- item 
           if p c                        --    ; if p c
                then return c            --        then return c 
                else failParse           --        else failParse }
```